# перерисовка WebView внутри ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, webview, adapter

В ListView через адаптер отображаю свой layout в котором находиться WebView, в WebView загружаю html текст, проблема в том что при прокрутке ListView, элементы списка скрываются и в итоге текст из WebView удаляется, потом когда возвращаюсь обратно, срабатывает getView из адаптера в котором загружается html и в итоге получаю скачки по списку из-за изменения высоты элемента списка (зависит от высоты WebView, т.е. при прокрутке элемент (который не видно) становиться минимальной высоты, а затем загружает html и становиться выше. В итоге прокрутка списка происходит скачками. Подскажите как можно это исправить?

Comment: может пересмотреть использование WebView? TextView тоже [может](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116191/5330439) отображать html

Comment: @TimurVI, думал об этом, использую для отображения комментариев с форума, а там смайлы, спойлеры, картинки и ссылки, так что не вариант наверное, TextView это все думаю не выведет.

Comment: а корень какой в layout с webview?

Comment: @TimurVI, LinearLayout

Comment: может имеет смысл задавать высоту webview по длине контента?

Comment: @TimurVI, как это определить?

Comment: @TimurVI, не вариант кстати, длинна контента меняется, там спойлеры и тд

Comment: [есть мнение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8457633/5330439), что webview лучше все таки так не использовать